# How to get the values of all the entries in a DataGrid in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I was working on an app and at some point i had to get the values entered in the entries that are in a DataGrid and then display them on a click of a button (just for testing ) but i didn't know how , should i bind it to a ObservableCollection of string or what ??
Here is the xaml code for refrence :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MarjaneStock.Maui.CreateOrderPage"
             xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Maui.DataGrid;assembly=Maui.DataGrid"
             Title="CreateOrderPage"
             Padding="0">

    <ScrollView>
       <Grid RowDefinitions="*,80">
           <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                             SelectionEnabled="False"
                             RowHeight="80"
                             HeaderHeight="60"
                             Margin="0,10,0,0"
                             FooterHeight="0"
                             BorderThickness="1"
                             MinimumHeightRequest="100"
                             HeaderBackground="#0B4B90"
                             MaximumHeightRequest="600"
                             VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             BackgroundColor="Black"
                             FontSize="18">
                    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Id" PropertyName="Id"/>
                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Product Name" PropertyName="ProductName"/>
                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Qunatity per unit">
                            <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Entry TextColor="White"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Qunatity per Package">
                            <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Entry TextColor="White"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridColumn>
                    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                        <dg:PaletteCollection>
                            <Color>#FFF</Color>
                        </dg:PaletteCollection>
                    </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                    <dg:DataGrid.RowsTextColorPalette>
                        <dg:PaletteCollection>
                            <Color>#000</Color>
                        </dg:PaletteCollection>
                    </dg:DataGrid.RowsTextColorPalette>
                </dg:DataGrid>
                <Button HeightRequest="60"
                        Command="{Binding ShowValuesCommand}"/>
       </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the view model (if needed) :

```
public partial class CreateOrderPageViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Return()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        DateTime deliveryDate;

        [ObservableProperty]
        DateTime orderDate;

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public async Task GetProductsList()
        {
            var productsList = new List<Product>();

            var productUrl = $"https://localhost:7282/api/Products/GetProductsInSectionAndSupplier/{SectionSupplier.SectionId}/{SectionSupplier.SupplierId}";

            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var ApiResponse = await client.GetAsync(productUrl);

                if(ApiResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var content = await ApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    productsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(content);
                }
            }

            if(productsList?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var product in productsList)
                {
                    Products.Add(product);
                }
            }
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        SectionSupplier sectionSupplier;

        public async void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            SectionSupplier = query[nameof(SectionSupplier)] as SectionSupplier;
            await GetProductsList();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task ShowValues()
        {
            //Showing data logic
        }

    }
```

One other question let's say i get the data of the entries how would i know which value entered in an entrie corresponds to which element ???

Comment: You can bind text from the Entry to your Product object property.  Or you can wrap your Product object into some other object with the property where entry text is will be bound.

Comment: Yes, you should use data binding

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/), you can directly bind `Text` property with the `ProductQuntity` of the Model:Product like below:

**XAML:**

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="Qunatity per unit">
        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                      <Entry 
                              Text="{Binding ProductQuantity}"
                              TextColor="White"
                              FontSize="18"
                              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
             </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
 </dg:DataGridColumn>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
[ObservableProperty]
public string productQuantity;
```

In response with another question:

> Let's say I get the data of the entries how would I know which value
> entered in an entire corresponds to which element?

You can search for the specific Id of the `Product` you want when traversing the `ObservableCollection<Product> Products`:

```
foreach (var p in Products) 
{
     if (p.Id == "theIdyouwant")
     {
          await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Messages for quantity", p.ProductQuantity, "OK");
     }
}
```

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.